# how to setup the class name in my case

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to combine the ng-class condition statements in my case.

I have the following statements.

```
<div ng-class="item.new ? 'newItem' : 'oldItem'; 'discount' : item.getType === true && item.getSave === true">{{item.name}}</div>
```

I am getting the parsing error.

```
Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected
```

I am not sure how to fix this. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'discount' ? item.getType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax instead:

```
<div ng-class="{newItem: item.new, oldItem: !item.new, discount: item.getType === true && item.getSave === true}">
```

Or alternatively put your logic in a function:

```
<div ng-class="getClasses(item)">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.getClasses = function(item) {
  return {
    newItem: item.new,
    oldItem: !item.new,
    discount: item.getType === true && item.getSave === true
  };
}
```

FYI: from that function you can return an object, or an array of classes, or a string.